# Group query by month only in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, sum

I have a three months list of sold items and their respective dates. I want to create a table that shows total items sold over each month (Sep, Oct, Nov), best selling item for each month.

This is what my data output looks like:

```
  ~dateshipped~  ~item~  

    9/3/19         A
    9/3/19         A
    9/5/19         B
    10/10/19       C
    10/12/19       D
    10/12/19       D
    11/13/19       D
    11/15/19       B     
    11/15/19       B
    11/18/19       A
```

Desired result: three columns: month//total item count//best item sold for that particular month

```
  ~month~  ~total_month~  ~best_sold~ 
   Sep           3             A             
   Oct           3             D
   Nov           4             B
```

Whats the simplest way for me to get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

try like below using cte

```
 with cte as 
 (
 select
 to_char(to_timestamp (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::text, 'MM'), 'TMmon')
 as month, count(*) as total_month
 from table_name group by 
 to_char(to_timestamp (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::text, 'MM'), 'TMmon')

  ) , cte2 as
   (
     select  to_char(to_timestamp (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::text, 'MM'), 'TMmon') as month, count(*) as total_month,item
    from table_name group by
   to_char(to_timestamp (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)::text, 'MM'), 'TMmon'),item
   )
  ,cte3 as
  ( select t1.* from cte2 t1 where
    t1.total_month=(select max(total_month) from cte2 t2 where t1.month=t2.month)
 ) select cte.*,cte3.item as best_sold from cte join cte3 on cte.month=cte3.month
 order by cte.month
```

output

```
month   total_month     best_sold
nov     4                B
oct     3                D
sep     3                A
```

[Online demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7eab760f3af0eb767d4febc0fe0ee6b3)

Comment: @mexica2 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7eab760f3af0eb767d4febc0fe0ee6b3 check the link

Answer (score 1):

A simple group-by followed by rank window function should do it:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped) AS month_num
         , item
         , SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)) AS total_thismonth
         , COUNT(*) AS total_thismonth_thisitem
         , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped) ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS item_rank
    FROM t
    GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateshipped)
           , item
)
SELECT *
FROM cte1
WHERE item_rank = 1
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=142912df65ca6bbac4678af7f32f05e0)